# Package dependency issue when testing for submissin to CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

I am developing an R package for which I wrote some test files using R package `testthat`and placed the files under `tests` folder. I ran `R CMD build` on a Linux machine with R version 3.0.0. The command failed because `testthat` package requires R version at least 3.1.0.

Two following things I can do, but I am not sure which is better.

1. I can remove whole things in `tests` folder, so that my R package will also work for R version less than 3.1.0. As I notice, test files are not required for building an R package. Those are only useful for the developer.
2. I can keep all test files, but explicitly mention `Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. The downside is that: (1) the package will be available to less users; and (2) more important, it depends on `testthat` package. Whatever updates there might affect my package potentially.

Which one do you think is better?

**[update]**

I followed the suggestion from @ hrbrmstr, which is, I first built the package using R 3.1.0, and then check it on a Linux machine with R 3.0.0. But I still failed. The log is as follows.

```
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package suggested but not available: ‘testthat’

The suggested packages are required for a complete check.
Checking can be attempted without them by setting the environment
variable _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to a false value.
```

Any ideas to fix this issue?Or should I take approach 1 or 2 as stated above?

Comment: Add `testthat` to `Suggests` vs `Imports` or `Depends` then you can keep the `R` dependency at `3.0.0`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. That's indeed what I did. ``Suggests: testthat``. But I still failed.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion - first build the pkg on 3.1 machine and then do an check of the pkg on 3.0. That doesn't work either. Any solutions?

Comment: Okay. But what I am doing now is to make sure that my package can pass CRAN checks on different platforms. How could I make sure that before INSTALL?

Comment: Use Docker or Vagrant to build VMs for R current and R-devel on a linux environement and windows or mac os (it only technically has to build on two). That's what most of us do. You can also submit a pkg to win builder via devtools::build_win()

Comment: You don't need devtools to submit to win-builder.  All you need is a ftp client; and I just deploy a two line shell script to push to devel and release at once.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel aye, but `build_win()` is _so_ convenient in a pkg :-)

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE move on from R 3.1.0 now.  Your package will simply get rejected.  R 3.2.* has more tests, and you are now expected to use R-devel as well.  You are not doing yourself favours by staying on a jurassic version.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, that's great to know. I will explore that.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, that sounds great. could you show me how you did that?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, yes I think you are right. Maybe I should move to new R version but not be bothered by ``testthat`` dependence issue.